# axios.post is sending a GET request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a chrome extension which uses react/axios. In that app I'm sending a post request like so:

```
export const createComment = payload => {
  const url = `${COMMENTS_BASE_URL}`;
  const promise = axios.post(url, payload);
  return { type: CREATE_COMMENT, promise };
}
```

Even though it's clearly axios.post(), the browser is sending a GET request to the url, which is not allowed (response 405). I've tried also using `axios({ method: 'post', ... })` but the same thing happens with the browser sending a GET request.

Comment: So this has something to do with the chrome extension you are embedding, as axios.post() should work on a normal webpage?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try to remove a trailing slash in **COMMENTS_BASE_URL** if you have it.

i.e. use `'/resource'` instead of `'/resource/'`. We had the same problem.

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: I actually added a slash at the end and it started working. :-/ This is pretty odd behavior.

Comment: dude! you save me! I fought with this error for already two hours, I was thinking it was an error on my back end till I got tired of trying to see what and where and I came here.

Comment: In my case I had to use ```https://www.example.com``` instead of ```https://example.com```

Comment: Excellent, this solved for me! I found this issue happens when Axios receives a 301 (Moved Permanently), because it makes a redirect but also changes the method to "GET". The root cause is a badly formed URL (as Pavel said, check if slash in the end of the path may or may not be required). Since this may lead to unexpected behavior,  I opted to add `maxRedirects: 0` in the Axios config.

Comment: @Ray Pendergraph I had dropped it as a troubleshooting step, but had to add it back in to get it to work after changing to https

Answer (score 24):

In my case, My server use `https`

so, `http` => `https`

then problem solved.

Comment: This one helped me.

Comment: This was my case as well

Comment: The general case here is: you sent a request to the wrong URL. That could apply to different domains, different protocols, the wrong path, etc. Sometimes when you use the wrong URL you'll see failure, other times you'll get a redirect. The solution, of course, is not necessarily `http` -> `https` but rather.. double check your URL. See also [Margus Pala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53579331/666583).

Answer (score 4):

This happens then URL is redirected from POST call and GET happens after redirect. 
Most common redirects are caused by not needed trailing slashes or http redirecting to https

Answer (score 4):

In general this happens because

1. the original POST request is redirected by the server for some reason
2. chrome dev tools hides the initial POST request for some unknown reason
3. the browser follows the redirect and makes a GET request according to the `Location` header

Typical issues are:

- Lack of authentication leading to a `302` redirect.
- Use of `http` which the server redirects to `https` with a `301` or `302`.

However there could be other reasons so you should inspect the HTTP requests going to your server to understand what's going on. A tool like `tcpflow` is suitable. On nginx you can tail the `access.log` file. The idea is to understand what happens to the initial POST request so that the underlying issue can be corrected.

Comment: same with www. redirections

Comment: Thanks for posting a general answer (not "try tweaking the URL, good luck") and the most information about both the cause and techniques for resolution.