# Laravel + Vue + Axios issue with POST method

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, plesk

I am working on a Laravel 5.6 project which is stored on a VPS (we call it "production", despite there is no such created environment).

We also combined Plesk & Github to deploy the web app from our local environments to the server manually.

**The issue** is when I load some data from the APIs they return error 405 Method not allowed (**GET**)... but they actually are registered as **POST** in the `app.js` and in `routes/api.php`.

And the best thing is that in my local environment they work perfectly.

### Here some information:

#### The server:

- Ubuntu Server 14.04
- Apache / MySQL
- PHP 7.2.5

#### My computer:

- Windows 10 with XAMPP
- Apache / MySQL
- PHP 7.2.2

#### The Developer tool in every browser:

> **Request Method:** GET
> **Status Code:** *405 Method Not Allowed*

And here is the code within the `app.js`:

```
loadCountries: function loadCountries(total) {
    axios.post('/api/properties/countries/').then(function (response) {
        app.countries = response.data;
    });

    total = total <= this.countries.length ? total : this.countries.length;

    if (total) {
        var newArr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            newArr.push(this.countries[i]);
        }
        this.countries = newArr;
    }
},
```

**Note:** If I edit the same request in the developer tool and send it again but as a POST request it returns me everything ok, so the API seems to work fine on POST request.

Comment: This answer may be relevant to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611275/axios-post-is-sending-a-get-request

Comment: I couldn't find that answer... It solved my issue. Please answer. and Thank you

Comment: @Maramal: If it's working in postman then try to remove `/` from request. Try it like: `'/api/properties/countries'` because i think it's tried to find `'/api/properties/countries/'` and it's not defined in your routes!

Comment: @kozak please post as an answer

Comment: @Maramal, NP glad it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the trailing slash in your url.

Such as,

```
/api/properties/countries
```

Replacing that line in your original `app.js` would yeild this,

```
loadCountries: function loadCountries(total) {
axios.post('/api/properties/countries').then(function (response) {
    app.countries = response.data;
});

total = total <= this.countries.length ? total : this.countries.length;

if (total) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        newArr.push(this.countries[i]);
    }
    this.countries = newArr;
}
```

},

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue and i solve it by make computed attribute with full url like that

```
computed: {
    sendAnswersUrl: function () {
        return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname, +  "/api/properties/countries";
     }
  }
```

then when post using axios

```
axios.post(this.sendAnswersUrl, {
          group: this.id,
        })
        .then(data => {})
        .catch(() => {});
```