# Laravel The GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have laravel-vue application and one of my functions is running on post request but strange is that I get `GET` request error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

## code

`Route`

```
Route::post('distanceCost', 'Api\Front\CartController@distanceCost');
```

`Component`

```
sendShippingRequest() {
    // post request
    axios.post('/api/distanceCost/', this.form, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        //....
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
    });
}
```

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611275/axios-post-is-sending-a-get-request

Comment: Change `/api/distanceCost/` to `/api/distanceCost`

Comment: @STA same results

Comment: @STA hold on i think i need to re run `npm run prod` for result

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in response to a POST to `/api/distanceCost/`, Laravel will respond with a redirect to `/api/distanceCost`. Your browser will then send a request to `/api/distanceCost`, but this time, it will use GET and it will not send the post payload. This is why your server replies with an error code.